# grails: show list of elements from database in gsp

Tags: database, list, grails, gsp

in my grails app I need to get some data from database and show it in a gsp page.
I know that I need to get data from controller, for example

```
List<Event> todayEvents = Event.findAllByStartTime(today)
```

gets all Event with date *today*
Now, how can I render it in a gsp page?How can I pass that list of Event objects to gsp?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Rightly said @JamesKleeh. Sparing time [here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/) will save time writing a question. :-)

Comment: If you look at the Grails documentation you'll see that it is extremely skimpy in terms of really explaining how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can learn many of the basic concepts using Grails scaffolding. Create a new project with a domain and issue command `generate-all com.sample.MyDomain` it will generate you a controller and a view.

To answer your question create a action in a controller like this:

```
class EventController {

    //Helpful when controller actions are exposed as REST service.     
    static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

    def showEvents() {
        List<Event> todayEvents = Event.findAllByStartTime(today)
        [eventsList:todayEvents] 
    } 
}
```

On your GSP you can loop through the list and print them as you wish

```
<g:each in="${eventsList}" var="p">
 <li>${p}</li>
</g:each>
```

Good luck

Comment: i think that the call to controller event is missing in your example...how can showEvents can be called in that gsp?

Comment: This is assuming that you have a gsp named showEvents.gsp in a directory named event. Grails by convention will display the corresponded view for each action.

Comment: Try a new grails app with scaffolding, that will light up many of the confusions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is really what you meant, because in that case I suggest you to read some more on the grails :),  but anyway, for your case you can use render, redirect as well but here I am taking simplest way:

In your controller you have:

```
def getAllElements(){
    List<Event> todayEvents = Event.findAllByStartTime(today)
    [todayEvents :todayEvents ]
}
```

and then in the GSP(I assume you know about grails conventions, as if you don't specify view name, it will by default render gsp page with the same name as the function in the controller, inside views/):

```
<g:each in="${todayEvents}" var="eventInstance">
    ${eventInstance.<propertyName>}
</g:each>
```

something like this.