# Grails display data from database

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

I'm creating a Grails app following this tutorial: http://grails.asia/grails-tutorial-for-beginners-display-data-from-the-database

When I try to display data from database though, nothing happens. Below is my controller code:

```
def index(){
        def users = User.list();
        [users:users]
    }

def displayUsers(){
        if(User.count()==0){
            render 'User list is empty!';
        }else {
            render(view: 'userlist.gsp');
            //a little test
            println User.list().size();
            println User.count();
            for(User u : User.list()){
                println u.username;
            }
        }
    }
```

The User.count() is working, because I can see the usernames in console and userlist.gsp renders every time, but it seems that my view code doesn't see the list. Here's the userlist.gsp code:

```
<body>
    userlist.gsp
    <g:each in="${users}" var="user" status="i">
            <h3>${i+1}. ${user.username}</h3>
    </g:each>
</body>
```

What can be wrong with this code? I've been making precisely the same steps as in the tutorial above in my analogical app, but it doesn't seem to work. This is especially weird, since I've found a similar question under this link: [grails: show list of elements from database in gsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426953/grails-show-list-of-elements-from-database-in-gsp)
and it's been marked as accepted answer. Why does exacly the same way not work in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

render gsp view as follows (pass data as a model).

```
render(view: "userlist", model: [userList : User.list()])
```

Now get model data in gsp as follows.

```
<body>
    userlist.gsp
    <g:each in="${userList}" var="user" status="i">
            <h3>${i+1}. ${user.username}</h3>
    </g:each>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with many options:

1. rename your gsp action in controller from `def index()` to `def userlist()`

or rename `index.gsp` file to `userlist.gsp`

2. you can redirect to `userlist.gsp` with `${users}` object

So change in controller `def index()` action
 `[users:users]` to `redirect(action: "userlist", params: ["users": users])`

Note: 2nd method will show parameters in url.
[Refer Grails Doc](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html)

3. You can use `chain`
   e.g. `chain(action: "userlist", model: ["users": users])`

[Refer Grails Doc](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Controllers/chain.html)

[every gsp action (page) needs to be injected](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html#dependencyInjectionServices)

Comment: not sure if I understood the way you're suggesting. I've done something like this:
`def userlist(){
        def users = User.list();
        redirect(action: "displayUsers", params: ["users": users]);
    }`

view:
`<g:each in="${users}" var="user" status="i">
            <h3>${i+1}. ${user.username}</h3>
    </g:each>`
it doesn't seem to work for me